# How to increase the cell size with respect to the text size in detailTextLabel in iPhone.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

- In my App, I have a table view with cell style value2: (cell have two labels side by side).
- In **textLabel**, I displayed time: which was displayed in **timeLable**.
- in **detailTextLable**, I displayed comments which was entered in **commentsTextView**

---

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

}

cell.textLabel.text = timelabel.text;            
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = commentTextView.text;
    }
   //int x = cell.commentTextView.frame.size.height;


}

cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
return cell;
```

}

---

- I need to expand my cell size with respect to the length of comments entered in a text view  :'commentTextView' displayed in detailTextLabel.
- But the difference in the textLable (timelable text), it does not expand along with detailTextLabel

what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always tricky to get right, for the height you need to do implement something like this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *myLabel = "Hello World";
    CGSize labelSize = [[myLabel sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(160,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize.height;
}
```

Comment: -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellText = nil;
    UIFont *cellFont = nil;
    
    
    cellText = commentsTextView.text;
    cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:19.0];
    
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 10;
}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using     `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  delegae method of teble view , like : -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   CGSize lblSize ;
   NSString *lblString ;

   lblString = [[[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"aKey"];

   lblSize = [self getLebalSize:CGSizeMake(180, 9999) aLebalText:lblString aFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

   return lblSize.height + 10 ;
}

//getting labelsize
- (CGSize) getLebalSize : (CGSize) maxSize aLebalText : (NSString *) lebalText aFont : (UIFont *) font
{
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [lebalText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
    return expectedLabelSize;
}
```

Comment: your answer is useful to me to try like this thanku so much – maulik